# Jenkins: Does 'Static' and '(blocking)' imply that respective plugins are used?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

New to Jenkins and new to the way it is being used to my new workplace, I encountered the following in a job's page:

[image]

I would like to understand what I see, so a quick Google search yielded the following in regard to the use of 'Static' and '(blocking)' in Jenkins:

- [Static Code Analysis Plug-ins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins)
- [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin)

Are these the right places to look at for attempting to understand the meaning of these keywords in the context of Jenkins?

If not, what is the right place to find out about them?